# Redefinition using Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, redefinition

I cant understand why I have redefinition trying to run this example. Can anyone tell me?

```
using namespace std;

class Base {
        protected: int *value;
        public: Base() { 
           value = new int, 
          *value = 1; 
        };
        Base(int &n) { 
            value = new int[n]; 
        }
};

int main() {
        int x=2;
        Base zm;
        Base(x);
        system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: Should be tagged as `c++` but there's a pending edit I approved without noticing that was missing.

Comment: Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: I had error - redefinition, diffirent basic types but Piotr Dajlido helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Witaj Przemeku Na StackOverflow!***

**How about this?:**

```
class Base {
        protected: int *value;
        public: 
        Base() { 
           value = new int, 
          *value = 1; 
        };
        Base(int &n) { 
            value = new int[n]; 
        };
};

int main()
{
        int x;
        x = 2;
        Base base;
        base = Base(x); <--- fix
        return 1;
}
```

> **Proszę bardziej formatować kod! ;)**